# Automatically call a click handler to load a jQuery dialog box on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've got a page, on the page there is a button wrapped in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: AddNewThread, text: 'Add New Discussion'" class="btn new"></a>
```

This calls a function labeled as `AddNewThread`, now this function opens up a dialog Box using jQuery, and in the dialog box there is a text field that you enter text to, and this text is then pasted on the page using ajax.

**The problem:**
I want to remove the click event entirely; I want to have it on page load, it will load the text box, and the functionality is remaining the same, But I just don't know how to go about this.

Here's the code for the `AddNewThread` function:

```
function DiscussionViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.New = ko.mapping.fromJS(newDiscussion);
    self.Threads = ko.mapping.fromJS(threads, mapping);
    self.AddNewThread = function () {
        $("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog('open');
        ko.mapping.fromJS(newDiscussion, self.New);

        if (CKEDITOR.instances["txtDiscussioinDescription"] != undefined) {
            CKEDITOR.instances["txtDiscussioinDescription"].setData('');
        }
    };
    self.AddReply = function (thread) {
        $("#txtDiscussioinDescription").val('');
        self.LastDiscussionId(thread.New.ParentId());
        self.New.Title('');
        self.New.DiscussionId(thread.New.DiscussionId());
        self.New.Type(thread.New.Type());
        self.New.TypeId(thread.New.TypeId());
        self.New.Description('');
        self.New.ParentId(thread.New.ParentId());
        self.New.UserId(thread.New.UserId());
        self.New.User(thread.New.User());
        $("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog('open');

    };
    self.LastDiscussionId = ko.observable();
    self.SubmitReply = function (form) {
        var jForm = $(form);
        $("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog('close');
        var request = jForm.serialize();
        var discussionId = $("#DiscussionID").val();
        var parentId = $("#ParentId").val();
$.post(addDiscussionUrl, request, function (response) {
            if (response) {
                if ((discussionId == '' || discussionId == undefined) && parentId == '') {
                    $.post(summariesUrl, { type: type, objectId: objectId }, function (response) {
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(response, mapping, self.Threads);
                        $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
                    });
                } else {
                    self.LoadReplies(self.LastDiscussionId());
                }

            } else {
                alert("Error occured while adding discussion");
            }
        });


    };
    self.GetReplies = function (data) {
        var thread;

        if (data.IsMaximized() == true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.Threads().length; i++) {
                if (self.Threads()[i].DiscussionId() == data.DiscussionId()) {
                    self.Threads()[i].IsMaximized(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.Threads().length; i++) {
                if (self.Threads()[i].DiscussionId() == data.DiscussionId()) {
                    self.Threads()[i].IsMaximized(true);
                    self.LoadReplies(data.DiscussionId());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    };
    self.LoadReplies = function (discussionId) {
        var request = {
            discussionId: discussionId,
            type: type,
            objectId: objectId
        };
        $.post(threadsUrl, request, function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.Threads().length; i++) {
                if (self.Threads()[i].DiscussionId() == discussionId) {
                    self.Threads()[i].Replies.splice(0, self.Threads()[i].Replies().length);
                    for (var j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
                        self.Threads()[i].Replies.push(new ReplyModel(response[j]));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
        });
    };
    self.EditReply = function (dicussion) {
        self.New.Title(dicussion.Title());
        self.New.DiscussionId(dicussion.DiscussionId());
        self.New.Type(dicussion.Type());
        self.New.TypeId(dicussion.TypeId());
        self.New.Description(dicussion.Description());
        self.New.ParentId(dicussion.ParentId());
        self.New.UserId(dicussion.UserId());
        self.New.User(dicussion.User());
        self.LastDiscussionId(dicussion.DiscussionId());
        $("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog('open');
    };
    self.ToggleView = function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.Threads().length; i++) {

            for (var j = 0; j < self.Threads()[i].Replies().length; j++) {
                if (self.Threads()[i].Replies()[j].DiscussionId == data.DiscussionId) {
                    self.Threads()[i].Replies()[j].HasMore(!self.Threads()[i].Replies()[j].HasMore());
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
}
var discussionViewmodel = new DiscussionViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(discussionViewmodel, document.getElementById("dvThreads"));

$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    var dialog = $("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 720,
        height: 500,
        title: 'Discussion',
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            if (typeof DISABLE_FOR_DIALOG != 'undefined')
                DISABLE_FOR_DIALOG = true;
            CKEDITOR.replace('txtDiscussioinDescription');

        },
        close: function (parameters) {
            if (typeof DISABLE_FOR_DIALOG != 'undefined')
                DISABLE_FOR_DIALOG = false;
            if (CKEDITOR.instances["txtDiscussioinDescription"] != undefined) {
                CKEDITOR.instances.txtDiscussioinDescription.updateElement();
                CKEDITOR.instances.txtDiscussioinDescription.destroy();
            }

        }
    });
    dialog.parent().appendTo($("#dvDialogs"));
    $("#frmAddDiscussion").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = discussionViewmodel.SubmitReply;
    $("#frmAddDiscussion").bind('click', function () {
        CKEDITOR.instances.txtDiscussioinDescription.updateElement();
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: This isn't all your code (the end of the view model isn't present nor how you create an instance of it), but why not call `discussion.AddNewThread()` right after you call `ko.applyBindings`?

Comment: Thank you, I Added the rest of the code as you pointed out. How would calling discussion.AddNewThread() after ko.applyBindings work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the function at the appropriate time, which in this case is within your jQuery ready handler, right after this block:

```
$("#frmAddDiscussion").bind('click', function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.txtDiscussioinDescription.updateElement();
});
```

You should be able to just add:

```
discussionViewmodel.AddNewThread();
```

This will invoke the function the same way that knockout would have done through the `click` data binding.

Comment: Yay! Thank you! That worked great James, It called the function on page load. Now if i wanted to remove this from a dialog, and have it load via the page, what steps would I go through? Would I just take my instance of ckeditor and paste it into the page?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you're asking how to have the functionality that's in the dialog within the page itself... Yes?  I didn't look in detail through your code, so there might be other things related to the dialog that would need to be tweaked

Comment: Well it's using CKEditor, and in order to instance ckeditor i need to use the CKEDITOR.replace('Function');   to tell the page, 'load an instance of ckeditor here.' Right now it's loading in a dialog box, I'm not sure how i can get this to load without the dialog box and have it load inside a div for instance.

Comment: A jQuery dialog is just a glorified/styled div anyway, anything that works in a dialog should work in a normal page

Comment: try removing your `.dialog()` initialisation in your jquery ready handler and then also remove `$("#dvAddDiscussion").dialog('open');` in the `AddNewThread` function - you should get the same behaviour as you currently have, but without the dialog.  May end up in a wierd place on your page, but you can reposition/style it as you like if it works

Comment: Looks like part of the CKEditor initialistion is done in the jQuery dialog `open` handler too - you might need to do that at the end of the ready handler instead

Comment: "Looks like part of the CKEditor initialistion is done in the jQuery dialog open handler too - you might need to do that at the end of the ready handler instead" I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate a bit? (sorry i'm still a new programmer)

Comment: It's starting to get a bit of a drift from your original question here (how to invoke the click handler automatically) - perhaps you might want to draft a new question about moving the content out of the dialog?

Comment: Thanks James, I'll go ahead and create a new question. You've been enormously helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid that no one is really helping me out with this question, I'd hate to waste your time James but if you wouldn't mind continuing to help me out for a little bit more It would really be appreciated, you have no idea the amount of frustration this issue has caused.